# Apple Mail - Exchange Account - Sent mails going to Recipient's Junk

Tags: macos, email, exchange

I recently helped a friend with a 2015 iMac upgrade to Mojave; it was on Yosemite.

I ran a backup, performed the install, did the updates; all good.

I then opened Mail, where she has 3 exchange accounts, and Mail would crash every time I made one in particular go online. I tried all sorts of things to remedy this but in the end I had no choice but to remove the account and add it in again. This went well. Or so it seemed.

Now, when she sends emails (from that account) they are going into her recipients junk/spam folder.

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Because the client *on the other end* is marking them as junk.  Ask that client why.

Comment: This all worked fine a week ago; why would it start happening now?

Comment: Because however the machine on the other end scores the email, has been changed.  Why are you so resistant to looking at the other end?

Comment: Because there was no issue before with regular recipients receiving email.